# Brightness not working in XFCE after using nomodeset in grub file in hp datu0327 laptop

Tags: boot, brightness, reboot, system-settings

Brightness is not working moreover the Power Manager Plugin is also not working
[see not able to add as the power manager plugin as the option to add it also not working when it comes to power manager plugin]

[1][1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhtcK.png

Comment: `nomodeset` override any graphics drivers and forces a generic VESA video mode. Additional functions obviously won't work. Why do you have it?

Comment: it enters in a bootloop when i didnt used nomodeset

Comment: What OS & release are you asking about?  Your chosen desktop isn't very specific.   (*if you are using `nomodeset` then many display functions are very basic and unconfigurable*)

Comment: So fix that first. That is the question you should be asking along with the basic information: Ubuntu release/version, Hardware specifications, etc.

Comment: Im using XFCE4 on ubuntu impish indri